# dealing with strange characters in a bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, unicode, biber

I use `mendeley` to generate my `bib` file so I have a very large list of items (3000+) and since `mendeley` collects the bibliography information sometimes from the pdf file, there may be errors and strange characters. I guess this is why I get the following error

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:∗ not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

What should I do? I use `Pdftexify` on `WinEdt8`. packages are up to date

```
\documentclass[11pt,captions=nooneline]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% For proper input encoding
    \usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
    \usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,isbn=false,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=99,doi=false,url=true]{biblatex} % place in the document preamble
    \addbibresource{D:/Gdrive/Drop/Dropbox/STATADO/paper/latex/p2/library.bib}
```

example of a bib item gone wrong:

```
@article{Biais2009,
author = {Biais, Bruno and Weill, Pierre-olivier},
file = {:D$\backslash$:/Gdrive/Drop/Dropbox/mendeley/Biais, Weill - 2009 - Liquidity shocks and order book dynamics ∗ - Unknown.pdf:pdf},
keywords = {bid-ask spread,limit-order book,liquidity,search},
pages = {1--51},
title = {{Liquidity shocks and order book dynamics ∗}},
year = {2009}
}
```

here I guess the `*` is bad...

Comment: Do you need all 3000 bibtex entries in this article? Can you limit the .bib file to some subset you actually cite?

Comment: well yes the idea is to have one large bibliography database that I can use with each different article. but I guess the problem here comes rather from the incoding... do you have an idea? many thanks for your help

Comment: You should show us one or two of that entries which causes the problem ... You know a lot of your problem but you do not tell us the relevant things. So we can only guess ...

Comment: @Noobie My strategy with Mendeley is to have a folder (in Mendeley) for each article I write, and when I want to cite something I put it in that folder. Then you can select all in that folder and export a specific .bib file for each article.  Its a bit more work, but it can save you much heartache when trying to sort out encoding issues because you'll have a much smaller subset of references to go through.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `bibencoding` option to `biblatex` explicitly?

Comment: @Jon , I tried to load the package as \usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,isbn=false,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=99,doi=false,url=true,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex} ... but stil i have the same error...

Comment: You either should give the undeclared input a sensible definition, e.g. with the newunicodechar package and then `\newunicodechar{∗}{$\ast$}`. Or you can call biber with the option `--output_safechars`. This will (hopefully) convert the utf8 chars to sensible commands, see the documentation of biber.

Comment: thank you ulrike for your suggestion. how can i use the output_safechars options? i have winedt.. should I add the line --output_safechars as a parameter in the execution mode of biber?

Comment: @Noobie are you sure you are running `biber`? PDFTeXify command in WinEdt 8 by default runs `bibtex`...

Comment: yes karl thanks for your remark. I set up biber.exe instead of bibtex ;-) actually i am able to generate a bibliography... when there is no conflift with the articles I cite in the text.. sob

Comment: @Noobie Write the name of the user preceeded by `@` if you want to notify him... Anyway I get the same errors as you. Ulrike's suggestion doesn't work for me. Notice that the character you have is not an asterisk. Replacing `∗` with `*` I get no errors.

Comment: If you make sure that the input fields in Mendeley contain correct information in the first place you will not run into errors. The `∗` character for example has no added value to the title, so you can delete it from the title. This does involve reviewing all the citations, but otherwise you will get a bibliography with all kinds of weird characters.

Comment: @Noobie If you don't find any better solution, use the "Replace" command in WinEdt. "Search for": `∗`. "Replace with": `*`. Then press "Replace All".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, let me thank @karlkoeller @jon @Ulrike Fischer @darthbith and @Bart Arondson for their help.

What I did :

1) export a small bib file containing all the citations I need. nothing more
2) correct manually the mistakes generated by mendeley
3) contemplate a well compiled pdf

thank you all, I hope this can help other mendeley users

Answer (score 0):

For vim users coming across this, I did a simple search for non-ascii characters in my `.bib` with `/[^\d0-\d127]`.

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987362/how-to-get-vim-to-highlight-non-ascii-characters